# How are the album thumbnails names made?

Tags: android, android-music-player

I am making a program that shows the album artworks of songs on my device. To do this,
I get the folder that contains those album thumbnails (`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs`) but the name of the thumbnails contained in that folder make no sens to me. For example, the name of all album thumbnails have this format: `1354042503656`. The names of the files have no extension, are made with 13 numbers
and all starts with 1354.

Does someone know what it means? I would like to associate the names of the album thumbnails with the appropriate album in my application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into the source code of android, I found the method that is setting the names of those thumbnails. [source code](http://omapzoom.org/?p=platform/packages/providers/MediaProvider.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/providers/media/MediaProvider.java;h=c73871d54353f8cfcba5af8b28ae174e25aee9af;hb=master) at line 3575. the thumbnails names are made like so `String name = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());`

So it is impossible to match albums in my application and the names in the folder :(.

hope it helps!